# Feeding a monadic expression into unless or when

Tags: haskell, monads

I often find myself writing code that looks like this:

```
import System.Directory (doesFileExist)
import Control.Monad (unless)

example = do
  fileExists <- doesFileExist "wombat.txt"
  unless fileExists $ putStrLn "Guess I should create the file, huh?"
```

Perhaps a better way is:

```
example2 =
  doesFileExist "wombat.txt" >>=
    (\b -> unless b $ putStrLn "Guess I should create the file, huh?")
```

What's the best approach here?

Comment: Binding to `unless` with `(>>=)` can be done with a section, ``something >>= (`unless` someAction)``, if `someAction` is short. If it isn't short, I think `do bool <- something; unless bool $ do whatever` is better.

Comment: You can use `mfilter`, which works even better if you embed your computation in ` MaybeT`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could define a helper function:

```
unlessM :: Monad m => m Bool -> m () -> m ()
unlessM b s = b >>= (\t -> unless t s)

example3 = unlessM (doesFileExist "wombat.txt") $ 
  putStrLn "Guess I should create the file, huh?"
```

It seems like `unlessM` would be very useful. But the fact that I don't see anything like `unlessM` (or with that type signature) on Hackage makes me think that there's some better way to handle this situation, one that I haven't discovered yet. What do the cool kids do?

Comment: Here's a version of it: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/cond/0.4.0.2/doc/html/Control-Conditional.html#v:unlessM

Comment: There's the [`extra`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.6/docs/Control-Monad-Extra.html) package which also provides `unlessM` and seems to be more actively maintained.

Answer (score 5):

I have made use of `flip unless` for such cases, but these types of combinators can get a little bit noisy.  With the `LambdaCase` extension, you could at least avoid using a name for the result of `doesFileExist`, though it would result in having to pattern match on `True` and `False`, which can look a little strange (depending on if you believe `if` is unnecessary or not).

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
import System.Directory (doesFileExist)
import Control.Monad (unless)

example' =
  doesFileExist "wombat.txt" >>=
  flip unless (putStrLn "Guess I should create the file, huh?")

example'' =
  doesFileExist "wombat.txt" >>= \ case
    True -> return ()
    False -> putStrLn "Guess I should create the file, huh?"
```